# Will my Nvidia GeForce GT 520 graphics card work with ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have an Nvidia GeForce GT 520 and was wondering if Ubuntu would be able to use it.

Comment: do you have GT520 or GT520m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's [supported](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/310.19/README/supportedchips.html). You'll want to install the proprietary Nvidia driver after installation for the best performance.

You can install it using "Hardware Drivers" application after installation of Ubuntu. It will suggest to install it.